# Sorting a list with a dictionary at items

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to sort this list by date.  Does anyone know a way that I can sort by the dictionary value inside of the list?  I'm using this for a Flask table, by the way.  I'm open to any new methods that would make this easier.

```
def Fights(self):
    fights = []
    for fight in self.fighter["Fights"]:
        fights.append(dict(Opponent=str(fight["Opponent"]),
                           Location=str(fight["Location"]),
                           Date=(fight["Date"]),
                           Result=str(fight["Result"]),
                           Round=str(fight["Round"]),
                           Time=str(fight["Time"]),
                           Win=str(fight["Win"])))

    return fights
```

Comment: try `sorted` function http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/python-sorted/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sorted` function, with the `key` parameter is what you're looking for!

I'm not sure about your case, but maybe the code you are looking for is:

```
return sorted(fights, key=(lambda fight:fight["Date"]))
```

(To replace what you currently are returning.)

The sorted function sorts a list. The key parameter is a function to apply to each element before sorting. For example:

```
sorted([1, 2, 3], key=(lambda x:(-x)))
```

Would return, `[3, 2, 1]`, because it sorts [-1, -2, -3], but then uses the original numbers in the output, if that makes any sense. (Although in that particular case, using reversed=True) would be better.

Comment: @JeremyLewallen Do you think you understand the `key` parameter? Did I explain it clearly enough? Just wanna make sure my answer is as clear as possible.

Comment: It's great.   I had to use reverse to make the list descending